# Переключение слайдов в bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Не понимаю почему сдвигаются вниз кнопки выбора слайдов:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ведь код страницы целиком:

```
  <!-- Навигация -->
        <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <!-- Кнопка отвечает за навигацию -->
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#responsive-menu">
                        <span class="sr-only">Открыть навигацию</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"><img src="images/math.png" class="img-rounded" alt="Cinque Terre" width="104" height="36"></a>
                </div>


                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="responsive-menu">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-sign-in fa-1x" aria-hidden="true" ></i>  Моя страница</a></li>
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Материалы<b class="caret"></b></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-circle-o-notch fa-1x" aria-hidden="true"></i>  Наш курс</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-circle-o-notch fa-1x" aria-hidden="true"></i>  Статьи пользоватлей</a></li>
                                <li class="divider"></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Написать статью</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">О нас</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Слайдер -->
        <div id="carousel" class="carousel slide">
            <!-- Индикаторы слайдов -->
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <li class="active" data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="0"></li>
                <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
            </ol>

            <!-- Слайды -->
            <div class="carousel-inner">

                <div class="item active">
                    <img width="2000" height="800" class="cerousel-imeges" src="images/universe.jpg" alt="">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <blockquote>
                            <p>
                                Цитата
                            </p>
                            <footer><cite title="Source Title">Автора</cite></footer>
                        </blockquote>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="item">
                    <img width="2000" height="800" class="cerousel-imeges" src="images/universe2.jpg" alt="">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <blockquote>
                            <p>
                                Цитата
                            </p>
                            <footer><cite title="Source Title">Автор</cite></footer>
                        </blockquote>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="item">
                    <img src="images/universe3.jpg" alt="">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <blockquote>
                            <p>
                                В математике нет настоящих противоречий.
                            </p>
                            <footer><cite title="Source Title">Карл Фридрих Гаусс</cite></footer>
                        </blockquote>
                    </div>
                </div>

            <!-- Стрелки переключения слайдов -->
            <a href="#carousel" class="left carousel-control" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
            </a>
            <a href="#carousel" class="right carousel-control" data-slide="next">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
            </a>


            <!--<a href="#carousel" class="left carousel-control" data-slide="prev">-->
                <!--<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>-->
            <!--</a>-->

            <!--<a href="#carousel" class="right carousel-control" data-slide="next">-->
                <!--<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-right"></span>-->
            <!--</a>-->

        </div>




        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <h3>Управление профилем:</h3>
                <p>
                    <!--<a href="#" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i></a>-->
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-default">Подписаться</a>
                    <a href="html/signup.html" class="btn btn-primary">Зарегистрироваться</a>
                    <a href="html/signin.html" class="btn btn-primary">Войти</a>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Выход</a><br>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-success">Кнопка 3</a>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-warning">Кнопка 4</a>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-info">Кнопка 5</a>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger">Кнопка 6</a>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-link">Кнопка 7</a>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Кнопка</a>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Кнопка</a>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Кнопка</a>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">Кнопка</a>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <!-- Кнопка на всю ширину -->
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block active">Кнопка</a>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block disabled">Кнопка</a>
                    <button class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block" type="submit">Отправить</button>
                    <input class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block" type="submit"  value="Отправить">
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>



        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-4"></div>
                        <div class="col-md-4"></div>
                        <div class="col-md-4"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: по моему не хватает закрывающего тега div

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Еще одна небольшая ошибка - нет закрывающего карусель тега `</div>`

Получилось:

```css
.carousel-inner img {
  display: block;
  width: 600px;
  height: 500px !important;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  
  <div class="container">
    <!-- Навигация -->
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <!-- Кнопка отвечает за навигацию -->
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#responsive-menu">
            <span class="sr-only">Открыть навигацию</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"><img src="images/math.png" class="img-rounded" alt="Cinque Terre" width="104" height="36"></a>
        </div>


        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="responsive-menu">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-sign-in fa-1x" aria-hidden="true" ></i>  Моя страница</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Материалы<b class="caret"></b></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-circle-o-notch fa-1x" aria-hidden="true"></i>  Наш курс</a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-circle-o-notch fa-1x" aria-hidden="true"></i>  Статьи пользоватлей</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">Написать статью</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">О нас</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Слайдер -->
    <div id="carousel" class="carousel slide">
      <!-- Индикаторы слайдов -->
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li class="active" data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="0"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      </ol>

      <!-- Слайды -->
      <div class="carousel-inner">

        <div class="item active">
          <img width="2000" height="800" class="cerousel-imeges" src="http://economictimes.indiatimes.com/thumb/msid-50941625,width-640,resizemode-4/mughal-gardens-in-full-bloom.jpg" alt="">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            <blockquote>
              <p>
                Цитата
              </p>
              <footer><cite title="Source Title">Автора</cite></footer>
            </blockquote>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="item">
          <img width="2000" height="800" class="cerousel-imeges" src="http://media.gettyimages.com/photos/cosmos-flowers-in-full-bloom-picture-id467213949?k=6&m=467213949&s=170667a&w=0&h=y5trnQg5YGRZ8hiJQdpHW3fI2QsyPk547IslOsA2zuQ=" alt="">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            <blockquote>
              <p>
                Цитата
              </p>
              <footer><cite title="Source Title">Автор</cite></footer>
            </blockquote>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="item">
          <img src="http://keenthemes.com/preview/metronic/theme/assets/global/plugins/jcrop/demos/demo_files/image1.jpg" alt="">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            <blockquote>
              <p>
                В математике нет настоящих противоречий.
              </p>
              <footer><cite title="Source Title">Карл Фридрих Гаусс</cite></footer>
            </blockquote>
          </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Стрелки переключения слайдов -->
        <a href="#carousel" class="left carousel-control" data-slide="prev">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
        </a>
        <a href="#carousel" class="right carousel-control" data-slide="next">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
        </a>


        <!--<a href="#carousel" class="left carousel-control" data-slide="prev">-->
        <!--<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>-->
        <!--</a>-->

        <!--<a href="#carousel" class="right carousel-control" data-slide="next">-->
        <!--<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-right"></span>-->
        <!--</a>-->

      </div>
    </div>



        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <h3>Управление профилем:</h3>
                <p>
                    <!--<a href="#" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i></a>-->
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-default">Подписаться</a>
                    <a href="html/signup.html" class="btn btn-primary">Зарегистрироваться</a>
                    <a href="html/signin.html" class="btn btn-primary">Войти</a>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Выход</a><br>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-success">Кнопка 3</a>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-warning">Кнопка 4</a>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-info">Кнопка 5</a>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger">Кнопка 6</a>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-link">Кнопка 7</a>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Кнопка</a>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Кнопка</a>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Кнопка</a>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">Кнопка</a>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <!-- Кнопка на всю ширину -->
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block active">Кнопка</a>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block disabled">Кнопка</a>
                    <button class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block" type="submit">Отправить</button>
                    <input class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block" type="submit"  value="Отправить">
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>



        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-4"></div>
                        <div class="col-md-4"></div>
                        <div class="col-md-4"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    
  </div>
    
</div>
```

*Опять со своими картинками и стилями, для наглядности))*